# rotated crop in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to crop a picture on right on along the contour. The object is detected using surf features and than i want to crop the image of extactly as detected. [image]

When using crop some outside boundaries of other object is includes. I want to crop along the green line below. OpenCV has `RotatedRect` but i am unsure if its good for cropping.

Is there way to perfectly crop along the green line

Comment: It looks like that rect is skewed due to perspective distortion, so you'll never get a clean crop by just rotating.

Comment: Anything useful [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you get you get your example from http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html, so  what you can do is to find the minimum axis aligned bounding box around the green bounding box, crop it from the image, use the inverted homography (`H.inv()`) matrix to transform that sub image into a new image (call `cv::warpPerspective`), and then crop your green bounding box (it should be axis aligned in your new image).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the equations of the lines from the end points for each. Use these equations to check whether any given pixel lies within the green box or not i.e. does it lie between the left and right lines *and* between the top and bottom lines. Run this over the entire image and reset anything that doesn't lie within the box to black.

Not sure about in-built functionality to do this, but this simple methodology is guaranteed to work. For higher accuracy, you may want to consider sub-pixel checks.

Comment: It would probably be easier just to floodfill the rect and use it to mask the original image, but I don't think that's what the OP wanted.